# Show div and hide siblings when clicking on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to write the appropriate javascript or jquery to show a specific div when my clickable div is clicked, meanwhile hiding all other divs within the same class that were previously clicked.

HTML

```
<img src="images/Current system & actors.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" style="left:275px; position:absolute; top:247px; width:100%; z-index:1; " usermap="#mymap" >

<div id="items" >       
    <div class="sqtrigger" id="xcrudeoil" style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:200px; " onclick="MM_showHideLayers('crudeoil','','show')" ></div>
    <div class="sqtrigger" id="xNP" style="position:absolute; left:300px; top:200px; " onclick="MM_showHideLayers('NP','','show')" ></div>
</div>

<div id="info" >
    <div id="crudeoil" class="textbox" >Crude oil description </div>
    <div id="NP" class="textbox" >NP description</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function MM_showHideLayers() { //v9.0
    var i,p,v,obj,args=MM_showHideLayers.arguments;

    for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) {
        with (document) if (getElementById && ((obj=getElementById(args[i]))!=null)) {
            v=args[i+2];

            if (obj.style) { 
                obj=obj.style; v=(v=='show')?'visible':(v=='hide')?'hidden':v; 
            }

            obj.visibility=v; 
        }
    }
}
```

I've found information on doing this with `<area>` tag however I'd like to avoid rewriting my clickable divs to areas within my map because I have over 100 clickable divs and need a work around solution for now...

Example --> http://jsfiddle.net/berqK/4/

```
var links = document.getElementById('oshastatemap');

for (var i = 0; i < links.children.length; i++) {
    links.children[i].onclick = function(ev) {
        target_id = this.id.replace('x', '');
        s = document.getElementById(target_id);
        states = document.getElementsByClassName('show');

        for (var j = 0; j < states.length; j++) {
            states[j].className = '';
        }

        s.className = 'show';
    };
}
```

So, how can I adjust this code I've found for showing a div when a link is clicked, to showing a div when a **div** is clicked while still hiding the others?

In reference to my divs  ... 
How can I make id="xcrudeoil" show id="crudeoil" (and xNP show NP) while at the same time hiding all child divs of div id=info (or within class="textbox")?

Here is an sample of what I have working so far. (note: in my browser the divs appear but I can't see them in fsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/ZCantrall/Ru82F/6/

Thanks a lot in advance! I'd really appreciate ANY advice that you can offer.

*EDIT // Second attempt with the CSS from /jsfiddle.net/Ru82F/7/ and the following HTML & JS

```
<html><head>
    <title>IES</title>

<link href="IES.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" >

</head>

<body>

<div id="items" >       
<div class="sqtrigger" id="xcrudeoil" >Oil</div>    
<div class="sqtrigger" id="xNP" >NP</div>
</div>


<div id="info" >
<div id="crudeoil" class="textbox" >Crude oil description </div>
<div id="NP" class="textbox" >NP description</div>
</div>

<script> src="jquery-1.9.1.js" </script>
<script> src="jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js" </script>
<script>
    $('.sqtrigger').on('click', function(e) {
    var targetId = this.id.replace('x', '');    

    $('#info .textbox').hide();
    $('#' + targetId).show();
});
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: You are using inline javascript. Stop That! :-)

If you hide ALL the divs except the one you clicked how would you ever click the other divs?

Comment: will do :) thanks! Can you take a look at my second attempt and tell me what I'm doing wrong when inserting the jQuery script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small jQuery script will show the relevant div and hide the others when you click the triggers (there might be issues with the css, I removed it for this test):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sqtrigger').on('click', function(e) {
        var targetId = this.id.replace('x', '');    

        $('#info .textbox').hide();
        $('#' + targetId).show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru82F/7/

Comment: I haven't been successful inserting this jQuery script. It seems like exactly what I am looking for. I tried putting the script you suggested just before the </body> with a total of 3 <script> tags: two referring to the files jquery 1.9.1 and jquery migrate 1.1.0 and the final one referring to your script. Is this right? I'll paste what I'm talking about in my original post... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ZCantrall I've changed it to include the document ready function. Try that.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it's still not working even with the doc ready function. Do you think I've put the script in correctly as I explained in my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this...  ***http://jsfiddle.net/berqK/22/***

JQuery Code...

```
var links = document.getElementById('oshastatemap');

for (var i = 0; i < links.children.length; i++) {
    links.children[i].onclick = function(ev) {
        target_id = this.id.replace('State', 'Layer');
        $("div[Id^='Layer']").css('display','none');
        $('#'+target_id).show();
    };
}
```

Comment: A full "jQuery code" would be `$('#oshastatemap').children().click(...);`.

Answer (score 0):

This small jQuery script will show the relevant div and hide the others

$("target_div").nextAll().hide()
$("target_div").prevAll().hide()